# How to get id from a form after a post in headers with php?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to save two types of data where one belongs to another and they're linked with an id field so that's a parent -> child relationship.

The queries are saved as follows:
`insert into emails (email) values (`$email`)` and afterwards I need to add `insert into emailscontent (firstname, lastname, emailsID) values ('$firstname', '$lastname', $id)`, but I need to get the `id` of the first queries inserted data and I remember doing that by fetching the id from headers some time ago.

Can you please show me how to get that id? Or, if not necessary, how I can save those two inserts with a join or something similar?

Comment: What functions are you using to run the queries?

Comment: Please read documentation : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to fetch the `last_insert_id`

- [PDO.lastinsertid](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

```
$id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

- [MySQLi.lastinsertid](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

```
$id = $mysqli->insert_id;
```

Alternatively, you could pass it through `$_GET`.